# CMake can not determine linker language for target: fileloader

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I know there are already a few threads on this topic, however, after reading through many of them I have been unable to find a solution to my problem. I am working on a file loader/parser and am using CMake for the first time. My CMakeList.txt file is being used to import an XML parser (xerces) and currently looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(fileloader)

set(SRCS
        Source.cpp
)

include_directories(./
        ${SPF_ROOT}/xerces/win64/include/xercesc/dom
)

add_executables(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})

add_library(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET STATIC XMLString.hpp XercesDOMParser.hpp DOM.hpp HandlerBase.hpp PlatformUtils.hpp)
set_target_properties(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

When running my solution the error I am recieving is "CMake can not determine linker language for target: fileloader"

I am relatively new to c++ and completely new to CMake so hopefully I am missing something simple, but any and all help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
The code I am writing is on a non-internet enabled machine so I cannot copy and paste the entire code, however this is the except causing the issue:

```
...
#include "XMLString.hpp"
#include "XercesDOMParser.hpp"
#include "DOM.hpp"
#include "HandlerBase.hpp"
#include "PlatformUtils.hpp"

class XMLReader : public IFileReader {
public:
        XMLReader(){};
        void read(std::ifstream& file) {
        xerces::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
        xercesc::XercesDOMParser* parser = new xercesc::XercesDOMParser();
        parser->setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
        parser->setDoNamespaces(true);

        xercesc::ErrorHandler* errHandler = (xercesc::ErrorHandler*) new xercesc::HandlerBase();
        parser->setErrorHandler(errHandler);

        std::getline(file, line);
        newFile = line.c_str();

        parser->parse(newFile);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Xerces is not a header-only library. What did you expect this code to do? Also, can you please give the *exact* code and error generated by CMake. The code that you have posted does not generate the error that you mention in the title.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the full code, but we need a sample that is actually [runnable and reproduces the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your sample code currently fails to do both of these things.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have to retype any code over to add it in. But I've added the excerpt that is producing the error and the error itself is the name of the question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added:
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES([some name] PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C11)
to the end of my program and the error went away. After reading a million web pages I found https://kuniganotas.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/error-cmake-can-not-determine-linker-language-for-target/ and the solution was literally that simple! Hopefully this can help others with this error!

Answer (score 4):

`HEADER_ONLY_TARGET` is not a keyword argument.

If you want a header-only library, use an interface library:

`add_library(<name> INTERFACE [IMPORTED [GLOBAL]])`

Comment: For <name> do I put DOM or do I need to put the file path?

Comment: `name` is the name of the header-only library you want to create. Have you read the comprehensive documentation? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html?highlight=i

Comment: My issue is that I don't have a .lib file. I have a folder with close to 100 separate .hpp files. Is there any command that I can use to put a file path or do I need to list out the individual .hpp files I'm using?

Comment: @GabrielBritcher you can be lazy and use `file(GLOB...)` or you can do something like `ls *.h >> CMakeLists.txt` and let the unix shell do it for you once.

Comment: so I've changed my last 2 lines to: file(GLOB LIBS ${SPF_ROOT/xerces/win64/include/xercesc/dom/*.hpp          target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PRIVATE ${LIBS})                but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @GabrielBritcher `LIBS` represents a list of header files, not a list of libraries. Stop, read the manual, have a look at some examples on github