# CMake linking error with Eigen "CMake can not determine linker language for target"

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

Let me show the directory tree and the code first.

```
eigen-git-mirror // from https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror
CMakeLists.txt // (1)
main.cpp
CODES
--CMakeLists.txt
--A
----*.hpp
----**.hpp
----...
--B
----*.hpp
----**.hpp
----...
--CMakeLists.txt // (2)
```

CMakeLists.txt (1)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

project(PROJ)

add_subdirectory(eigen-git-mirror)
add_subdirectory(CODES)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" main.cpp)

target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen CODES)
```

CMakeLists.txt (2)

```
file(GLOB CODES_A "A/*.hpp")
file(GLOB CODES_B "B/*.hpp")

source_group("A" FILES ${CODES_A})
source_group("B" FILES ${CODES_B})

add_library(CODES
    ${CODES_A}
    ${CODES_B}
)

target_include_directories(CODES
    PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/A"
    PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B"
)

target_link_libraries(CODES PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)
```

Now when I compile the cmakelists file, it will finish the configuration, but produces an error `CMake can not determine linker language for target: CODES`. I thought the problem was that CMake couldn't detect the language for `CODES`, but even if I added `set_target_properties(CODES PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C17)` it gives a same result. What seems to be the problem, and how should I solve it?

Comment: Try setting the `LANGUAGE` in the [`project`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command.

Comment: Regarding the `LINKER_LANGUAGE` property, the language is `CXX` for C++.

Comment: CMake determines linker language for the target(library in your case) according to the extension of the **sources**, but you provide no *sources* for `CODES` target, only *headers*. If you want to create header-only library (without source files, that is without compilation at all), use that answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940599/3440745